# Applescript use google chrome to extract text

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, extract

I'm extracting text from a page on safari, everything work fine,
However I can't adapt this script to Google Chrome

Here is the Safari code

```
to getInputByClass2(theClass, num) 
    tell application "Safari" 
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 
    end tell
    return input 
end getInputByClass2
```

Here is the Chrome code

```
 to getInputByClass2(theClass, num) 
    tell application "Google Chrome" 
        set input to do JavaScript "
document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;" in document 1 
    end tell
    return input 
end getInputByClass2
```

have error "Expected end of line but found identifier."

Comment: Is that double quote meant to be there at the end of this line: `set input to do JavaScript "`, or should it be on the line regarding document.getElements..., etc?

Answer (score 1):

The command and the syntax for "**Google Chrome**" is not the same.

You must use the `execute javascript` command instead of `do javascript`.

And you must specify a tab from a window instead of `in document 1`.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of window 1 to set input to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "')[" & num & "].innerHTML;"
end tell
```