# AppleScript : Copy all items of a list in the clipboard

Tags: list, google-chrome, safari, applescript

I'm extracting a list of data from a database on a website,

1. How can I go set the results of items in my list to the clipboard, excluding the first result with is just a wrong link
2. How can I use this script in Chrome instead of Safari?

   set dataINeedList to my getInputByClass2("sortable dataPersonId", 1)
       -- to get the tenth value, use this --> item 10 of allData

   ```
   to getInputByClass2(theClass) -- this return a list of values
       tell application "Safari"
           set r to do JavaScript "var outPut=[]; var arr=document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClass & "');for (var i in arr) {outPut.push(arr[i].innerHTML)};outPut;" in document 1
       end tell
       return strings of r --- this remove all 'Missing Value' from a list of strings
   end getInputByClass2

   set listSize to count of dataINeedList ## number of dataINeed founds

   set theResult to item 2 of dataINeedList

   ##repeat with theItem in dataINeedList ## not working
   ##  set the clipboard to theItem ##
   ##end repeat ##
   ```

Comment: For the second question, you have already asked this question. Check the answer : [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299708/applescript-use-google-chrome-to-extract-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, it's like this:

```
set x to {"a", "b", "c"}
set the clipboard to items 2 thru -1 of x
```

Comment: That perfect, many thanks, PS would you know how to use this in Chorme?

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't have chrome, and i've no knowledge of javascript :( i guess that, if chrome support javascript, this applescript should work in the same way.

Comment: Just a really last question, any idea how to replace the space and return to ligne for a coma?